# Custom Redirection of A Page On User Role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am working with `WooCommerce` and in the website, there are three specific users. i) **Admin** ii) **Vendor** iii) **Customer**. So what I want is to redirect to a specific page, when the user role is **Vendor**. So I am hoping there would be a way to do it, something like the below:

```
function vendor_dashboard_redirect() {
    if (condition) {
        redirect("To The Default WordPress Dashboard");
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'vendor_dashboard_redirect');
```

I am expecting there would be an appropriate way to do it and stuck with it for a while.

Comment: maybe [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

Comment: Tried with that @Richard. But didn't work. Guess, I missed something in the condition. Do you have any alternate on this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to check roles without creating a custom function. You can obtain an array of the current user's roles with [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user): `wp_get_current_user()->roles`, then loop over them to check if the user has the role. But I don't know if this will account for a user having multiple roles.

Answer (score 1):

This shoud work. Change the $vendor_role variable to your custom role identifier:

```
function vendor_dashboard_redirect() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user  = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = $user->roles;
        $vendor_role = 'vendor';

        if ( in_array( $vendor_role, $roles ) === true ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('/') );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'vendor_dashboard_redirect');
```